Sample/Hold Capacitor Not Holding As Expected
I'm working on a circuit to measure voltage across a shunt at 800ns and store it in a capacitor. Initially, the MOSFET switch is on, which allows the capacitor to track the input voltage from the shunt. At exactly 500ns, I open the NMOS switch, which should isolate the capacitor and discharging the stored voltage slowly through the 10MΩ resistor.
The problem is that when I open the switch, the capacitor doesn't hold the voltage—it keeps following the input. I found that the voltage swinging to negative voltage range may be the cause (not certain) since adding a diode between the capacitor and the NMOS source fixes it, but the voltage drop from the diode is too large for the small signals I'm measuring.
Is there any way to solve this without using a diode?




Hi properly because of the intrinsic diode in nmos transistor

What is the drain to source capacitance (output capacitance) of your MOSFET at low voltages?

If you bias the MOSFET to force it *off * completely, does that help?

Could you please indicate which node is V(N022)?

I have biased the FET with a voltage high enough such that I am certain it would be off, it makes no difference unfortunately. V(N022) is the input to the FET.

I suggest a couple of fixes:

The body connection must go to the negative-most potential. In case the body voltage goes above the Source or Drain by one diode turn-on voltage, the MOSFET operation changes significantly.
By the same virtue, the input must swing above zero to avoid pushing the N+ junction on the Source or Drain below zero. For example, when Vg = 0 and the FET is nominally off, the input swings to -5 V, partially turning the FET on and injecting charge (and noise).
Even when the FET is OFF, you will have clock feed-through from its Gate-Drain capacitance and input leakage from its Source-Drain capacitance.

If you clearly indicate which plot indicates what, I can edit my answer to point out the issue more specifically.

I redrew your schematic to help show the intrinsic diode, but that does not appear to be your only issue.  Without more of the schematic, and a properly drawn one showing power and ground references, I don't see how this circuit works at all.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thank you. I think not shown is the input to be sampled (the original photo seems clipped) which connects to the 5 Ohm resistor and the FET drain.

Thats correct. I am really just measuring the current using the shunt but I am only interested in the current pulse occurring in the first 800ns.
